# Current base_url (secure/unsecure?) in block

Tags: static-block, secure, variables

I want to make some links in a CMS static block. I use one of the `base_url` variables... for example:

```
<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}customer/account">Account</a>
```

I can make it either `secure` or `unsecure`... however I don't know if there's a way (I haven't found one, however searching is proving difficult) to have the "current" `base_url`: if the user is on `https` then use the `secure`, if the user is on `http` then use the `unsecure`.

Is that possible at all on CMS static blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you've found your answer by this time, but I'll answer it for future Googlers:

You shouldn't use a `config` directive for this, but use `{{store url="customer/account"}}`. It produces the same results as `Mage::getUrl()`, so automatically takes care of secure URLs.

Comment: Oh yes, I had found it... forgot I had made this question at all!! But correct answer, let me mark it :-)